# Using SQL Join and Update together

Tags: sql

I'm *attempting* to update a table using a join statement, but it isn't exactly working out.  I need to be able to update a certain row in the database when one condition is true, using data from a different table.  Here is what I have so far, maybe I am close and someone could provide some insight?

```
UPDATE Project
   SET Project.SumAssessments = SUM (Assessment.Amount)
 FROM Project
 JOIN Assessment ON Project.SumAssessments = SUM (Assessment.Amount)
WHERE Assessment.ProjectCode = @ProjectID
  AND Project.ProjectID = @ProjectID
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Which DBMS? And *isn't exactly working* is not an error message I have ever seen in any DBMS I worked with. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: So if I am getting this... you have a sum column that will be on every row? That will store the sum from the same table? Perhaps your table design needs some refactoring?

Comment: That's looking like MySQL specific syntax.

Comment: The current code wouldn't change anything, the `SET` is updating a value that based on the `JOIN` would already equal that value.  I could easily fix your syntax to make it work, but the code would have no effect.  We need to know what you're actually trying to update and on what condition, it currently makes little sense.

Comment: I'm getting this "An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
"

Comment: I cant understand what exactly you want to achieve from it. You are updating the column SumAssessments with the SUM (Assessment.Amount) where as your are applying equal inner join on same column, can understand why you want to update this column if there are already equal?

Comment: Ok, I was a little vague.  Specifically, this is a stored procedure that should update the row in the table 'Project' where a parameter, "@ProjectID", is equal to the column of that row which is named ProjectID.  The column that is to be updated in the table 'Project' is 'SumAssessments'.  I want the column 'Sum Assessments' from the table Project to be set to the SUM of all of the values in the table 'Assessment' where the column 'ProjectCode' in the table 'Assessments' is equal to the parameter '@ProjectID'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would get rid of the column entirely. It violates one of the most basic rules of proper database design. Don't duplicate data in your database, because it will pretty much always end up out of sync and even when it doesn't it will require extra maintenance and care. There are **VERY** rare cases where this should be violated. Your situation is almost certainly not one of those cases, even if you think it is. With proper indexing there should be no need for that column.

Second, there's no need to join on the Assessment table based on the `SUM`. You're already joining based on the project code, you just didn't put that condition in your `ON` clause where it belongs. Even better, you could just use a subquery to avoid the need for a `GROUP BY`. Since you're using what I assume is the Primary Key (ProjectId) the subquery should perform fine.

```
UPDATE Project
SET Project.SumAssessments = (
        SELECT SUM (Assessment.Amount)
        FROM Assessment
        WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectID
        )
 FROM Project
WHERE Project.ProjectID = @ProjectID
```

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the help!  I'm very new to SQL, so these concepts are very new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume you're trying to update the SumAssessments column, not query based off of it, so the SUM function should not appear in your join clause.  You don't need a join at all, and despite these 'sum' columns being a bad idea, here's how you can accomplish what you wanted:

```
UPDATE Project set SumAssessments = (
    select SUM(Amount) from Assessments where ProjectCode = @ProjectID
) 
where ProjectID = @ProjectID
```